# get the last 30 records from mysql but not the very last 1

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have been trying to figure out/ searching about how to do this but failed.

I have table with id as primary key and auto incremental and and a column clickers which counts member clicks. What I'm trying to do is average the value of "clickers" of the last 30 records except last very last 1

```
SELECT AVG(clickers) AS avgClickers FROM sitelogs_daily_stats ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 30
```

But this code includes the last records. I want to skip that one.

Any help would be very helpful.

Comment: can you expand your question more? or add details like sample records with desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it in derived query:

```
SELECT 
    AVG(clickers) as avgClickers
FROM 
    (
        SELECT clickers 
        FROM sitelogs_daily_stats 
        ORDER BY id DESC 
        LIMIT 1,29
    ) AS t1
```

Notice in the derived query, we are selecting the records of interest, and then averaging them in the outer query.

Comment: `SELECT AVG(ID) FROM table LIMIT 1` gives you same result as `SELECT AVG(ID) FROM table LIMIT 1000000`

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski Yeah, good catch.  Please see revised answer.

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski - performance issues are quite relative.  In any rational scenario where caching isn't needed, I doubt this will be an issue either.

Comment: Thank you very much! just what I needed! One question. you used LIMIT 2,29 that means this averages the last 29 records except the last 2 right? so if my last record's id is 100 the sample you gave averages the records from 98,97,96.. to 69 right?

Comment: @Keith Varias,yeah that's right.`limit 1,29` is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT AVG(clickers) AS avgClickers
FROM sitelogs_daily_stats
WHERE id BETWEEN
    (SELECT MAX(id)
     FROM sitelogs_daily_stats) - 29 AND
    (SELECT MAX(id)
     FROM sitelogs_daily_stats) - 1
```